# Generating random String out of a few user input options using java math.random?

Tags: java, string, random

Using Java, how do I select a random option (out of two user input items) using math.random where I assign different values to represent the different input items?

I need to create user input for 2 items, then use math.random to randomly choose one of the items.

Comment: Please post your code, along with the inputs/outputs, and explain why this does not do what you want it to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that in this way:

```
    String input1 = "Input 1";
    String input2 = "Input 2";
    int x = (int) ((Math.random() * (2)) + 0); //Generate random number between 0 and 1
    String randomString = "";
    if (x == 0) {
        randomString = input1;
    } else if (x == 1) {
        randomString = input2;
    }
    System.out.println(randomString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Although unclear what you mean in your question, this might help you randomly pick from 2 possible values. It uses the ternary operator (`condition ? expression : expression`), which has the value of its first expression in the case that its condition is `true`, and has the value of its second expression in the case that its condition is `false`.

```
String option1 = "I am the first option";
String option2 = "I am the second option";

String randomOption = new Random().nextBoolean() ? option1 : option2;
```

If you need to do this multiple times, you could consider reusing your `Random` instance.